# Why my golang template is not picking the external javascript file?

Tags: go

I tried so many suggestions from stack overflow but none seems to work. I was not able to pick the external js file.

My main function:

```
package main

import(
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/rs/cors"
    "text/template"
)  

func GetPeopleEndpoint(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html")
    t, _ := template.ParseFiles("index2.html")
    t.Execute(w, nil)
}

func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    people = append(people, Person{ID: "1", Firstname: "Nic", Lastname: "Raboy", Address: &Address{City: "Dublin", State: "CA"}})
    people = append(people, Person{ID: "2", Firstname: "Maria", Lastname: "Raboy"})

    fmt.Println(people)

    router.Handle("/files/", http.StripPrefix("/files/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("."))))
    router.HandleFunc("/people", GetPeopleEndpoint)

    c := cors.New(cors.Options{
        AllowedOrigins: []string{"http://localhost:3000"},
        AllowCredentials: true,
    })

    // Insert the middleware
    handler := c.Handler(router)

    //  handler := cors.Default().Handler(router)
    http.ListenAndServe(":12345", handler)
}
```

All my files are in the same directory.

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>

  </head>
  <body>
    This is page2

    <div id='newdiv'>

    </div>
  </body>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="app2.js">
  </script>
</html>
```

The error I'm getting is "GET http://localhost:12345/app2.js". I don't know where I'm doing the mistake.

Comment: "GET http://localhost:12345/app2.js" isn't an error, it's an HTTP request. What is the actual error? 404 Not Found?

Comment: Also you've defined the route for your files on disk to be `/files/`, but you're not using that in your reference in the HTML; perhaps `src="app2.js"` should be `src="files/app2.js"`?

Comment: @Adrian There is nothing specific like 404 which caused more confusion

Comment: What's generating the error? Web browser?

Comment: @Adrain Web browser. The app2.js is in the current directory. I gave the complete path to the files but it still didn't work.

Comment: It doesn't matter where it is on disk; your handler is setting the route as `/files/`, which means that's where you'll be able to load them from via HTTP. If you're using a web browser, you should be able to get the actual error from the developer tools; if your browser doesn't give you this, try a browser with better developer tools (e.g. Chrome/Chromium).

Comment: @Adrian I though this is the place where my server looks for app2.js (http.FileServer(http.Dir("."))).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147210/discussion-between-adrian-and-sarath-velamuri).

Comment: @Adrian Yes it 404 not found. I created a new directory and placed this app2.js in that. It is still the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

```
router.Handle("/files/", http.StripPrefix("/files/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("."))))
```

Means that requests coming in for URLs under "/files/" will be served from files on disk in the current directory, with the "/files/" prefix removed.
So if you want a file in the current directory named `app2.js`, then the URL must be `/files/app2.js`.

`router.Handle` defines what handler will handle a given path. In this case, that path is `/files/`. Because of the trailing slash, the same handler will be used for all URLs beginning with `/files/`.

`http.StripPrefix` is a handler *wrapper*. It takes the incoming request, strips off the given prefix (in this case, `/files/`), removes it from the URL path, and then passes the request on to the handler passed to `StripPrefix`.

`http.FileServer` serves files out of a `http.FileSystem`, in this case provided by `http.Dir`. `http.Dir` exposes the files in a directory, in this case the current working directory (`"."`).

So, in total: requests beginning with `/files/`, will have the `/files/` part removed, then whatever is left, that file path will be looked for in the current working directory, and if it is found, it will be served. So, `/files/app2.js` will serve `./app2.js`. Your HTML must reference `/files/app2.js`, **not** `app.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have directory structure:

```
<src-dir>
   static
   templates
   ...
```

And you map handler you're using `http.StripPrefix`

```
router.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))))
```

Update this line to-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/app2.js"></script>
```

Now you can access the file via `http://localhost:12345/static/app2.js`

Comment: No, you can't. That's not what `StripPrefix` does.

Answer (score 0):

Writing `http.FileServer(http.Dir("."))` is generally a bad idea because it will expose not only your .js files but also you .go files, making you code visible via http requests. For example http://localhost:12345/main.go will make the browser deliver your source code as text.

The best practice should be to collect your static files (js, css, html...) in seperated directories, or just in one, like for example a "resources" package.

Try then with

```
http.Handle("/files/", http.StripPrefix("/files/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("resources"))))
```

This code will do the work and allow you to access all your files that are under `/resources` with the url prefix `/files`. For example:
 `http://localhost:12345/files/app2.js`

Comment: I've never written a backend code and having a hard time understanding how the routes, etc work. I'm going through some blogs on how to secure the web application from most of the attacks. If you have any thing good in your mind, please suggest some.